# how to use the service ChangeDetectorRef to update a view in Angular 12

Tags: angular

I need to traslate my web app in two languages I created all properties of the object in two languages.

```
export class Room{
    _id: any;
    constructor(
      public title: string,
      public titleEs: string,
      public description: string,
      public descriptionEs: string,
      public availablecouples: string,
      public availablecouplesEs: string,
      public bills: string,
      public billsEs: string,
      public deposit: string,
      public depositEs: string,
      etc...
```

this is the view room.component html

```
<span class="form-inline">
                        <select 
                            class="form-control" 
                            #selectedLang 
                            (change)="switchLang(selectedLang.value)">
                          <option *ngFor="let language of translate.getLangs()" 
                            [value]="language"
                            [selected]="language === translate.currentLang">
                            {{ language }}
                          </option>
                        </select>
                      </span>
```

the above code is the button for Spanish and English

```
  switchLang(lang: string) {
    this.translate.use(lang);
    this.cdRef.markForCheck();
    if(this.translate.use('en'))
    {
      this.translateEn = true;
    }
    else if(this.translate.use('es'))
    {
      this.translateEn = false;
    }
  }

<div *ngIf="translateEn == true; then thenBlock else elseBlock">
</div>
<ng-template #thenBlock>    
 <h4>{{ room.titleEs }}</h4>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #elseBlock> 
<h4>{{ room.title }}</h4>
</ng-template>
```

the web app load by default in English but when I change to spanish the title changes but if I change again to English the title doesnt change to English.

how to detect if the

```
<select 
                            class="form-control" 
                            #selectedLang 
                            (change)="switchLang(selectedLang.value)">
                          <option *ngFor="let language of translate.getLangs()" 
                            [value]="language"
                            [selected]="language === translate.currentLang">
                            {{ language }}
                          </option>
                        </select>
```

select has changed to reload the view with CahngeDetectorRef?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this if not tried already:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';        
...        
constructor(private changeDetectorRefs: ChangeDetectorRef) { }        
...

switchLang(lang: string) {
    ...
    this.changeDetectorRefs.detectChanges();
    ...    
}
```